# Is there any Visual Studio Pluggin or tool to replace auto by the deduced type for non template code?

Tags: c++, auto

My colleagues don't appreciate not seeing the type and I don't appreciate doing the work of a compiler.

Comment: If you hover the mouse over `auto`, it will show the actual type.

Comment: Hm. The type is right there in the initialization?

Comment: @sweenish I'm don't work to waste my time, especially if a tool can do it. We probably value differently our time. And I say colleagues, not my boss.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili but can I replace it in one click?

Comment: @DevSolar I do `auto t = obj.GetTimer();` and it's obvious that the type is Timer

Comment: Yeah using auto takes the code to a higher abstraction level, it lets you focus on WHAT code is doing instead of HOW it is implemented. The thing is they probably must get used to it and feel that they are losing control instead of gaining clarity. But that's my two cents

Comment: @P Kramer when reading the code of others I can see the value of seeing the type. But I don't want to waste my time typing all the types every time a declare a variable when the compiler or a tool can know this information.

Comment: @Fractale no, because that is impossible in the general case. Consider the duplicate question.

Comment: @PKramer I think you are right, but I can understand that seeing the type help you understand the code sometimes. I understand their point, it's just a lot of effort that can be automated. I like writing with auto because I'm not trying to understand what I type. I want to get the code out of the way. If I can do it when my code is done, I will love it!

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I'm not sure to have understood. it's not possible for a template right? but it's possible for all the other cases right? So just keep the auto in the template, I don't care about them. it's a corner case. And if Visual Studio is showing me the type when I hover the mouse, it can probably write it in the file right?

Comment: @Fractale such tools do exist (https://cppinsights.io/s/ecc89494) but I don't know if anyone has created a plugin for VS.

Comment: @sweenish: or making it usable inside a template, which was already mentioned in the question title, by way of exclusion.

Comment: @sweenish I'm looking for a tool to conform to the coding standards. I think that is a smarter way than making effort to apply rules that gets in the way.

Comment: Generally speaking, the *name* of the variable should be the expressive part. In your example of `auto t = obj.GetTimer();`, how about `auto timer = ...`?

Comment: @DevSolar i agree with you, i actually mistyped. I do `auto timer = ...`  or `Timer t = ... ` but I prefer the auto version too